# html dropdown event not working in amazon mobile Application page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

While trying to pay using Amazon pay in mobile device. html dropdown event not triggering. same select box postback working in amazon web browser and not working in Amazon mobile Application. I have tried both html and asp.net control.

**HTML:**

```
 <select id="drpSourceAccount" name="cdrpSourceAccount" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" class="accSel"></select>
```

**ASP.NET:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpSourceAccount" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="accSel" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="00">--------- Select an account ---------</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
```

Any suggestion will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked in browser mobile view? Also one of reason could be the design issue any other control is coming over your dropdown.

Comment: Yes Shekar, Mobile view it is working fine in browser. When using mobile App only facing this issue.